# How can I access open data for non-U.S. governments?

Tags: data-request

If I wanted to access US government open data, I would go to data.gov.

What would I do for other countries such as Canada, the UK, or Germany? Is there a master list of open data websites for at least the major countries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for OpenDataSoft which is behind Open Data Inception project.*

**Open Data Inception** is a project that aim to give a master list and a master map of every Open Data Websites. The data have been both gathered by us and crowdsourced.

- You [can find the map here](http://opendatainception.io/)
- Here's [a list by country](https://www.opendatasoft.com/a-comprehensive-list-of-all-open-data-portals-around-the-world/)
- And finally, [here are the data as an open dataset](http://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/open-data-sources%40public/table/)

There are other similar project if you prefer, [Open Data Websites by the OKFN](http://data.okfn.org/data/okfn/opendatasites), [OpenGeocodes](http://www.opengeocode.org/), and [tons of Github accounts](https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-public-datasets) listing datasets and databases.

Cheers